# insertar varios values en una sola columna -mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo ese código que inserta los datos en la tabla images y en las columnas file_name, file_path, tags y tags2. Lo que estoy buscando es que los datos de tags y tags 2 vayan a la misma columna pero no se cual es la forma correcta de escribirlo.
Esto es el código que tengo

```
$insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO images (file_name, file_path, tags, tags2) VALUES ('".$fileName."', '". $targetFilePath ."', '". $chk ."', '". $tags ."')");
```

Había probado a ponerlo así por lo que he leído pero no me funciona.

```
$insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO images (file_name, file_path, tags) VALUES ('".$fileName."', '". $targetFilePath ."', ('". $chk ."'), ('". $tags ."'))");
```

¿Alguien sabe cual es la forma correcta de ponerlo?

Gracias de antemano

EDITO

COPIO aquí mi código para que sea más fácil de entender

```
<?php
// Include the database configuration file
include 'dbConfig.php';
include '../helpers/main_helper.php';
$statusMsg = '';

// File upload path
$targetDir = "../uploads/";
$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
//checkbox tags
$checkbox1 = $_POST['checktags'];
$chk="";
foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1)  
    {  
        $chk .= $chk1.",";  
    }
//text tags    
$tags = $_POST['tags'];

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    // Allow certain file formats
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf', 'ppt', 'pptx');
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
        // Upload file to server
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
            // Insert image file name into database
            $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO images (file_name, file_path, tags, tags2) VALUES ('".$fileName."', '". $targetFilePath ."', '". $chk ."', '". $tags ."')");
            if($insert){
                $statusMsg = "El archivo ".$fileName. " ha sido subido correctamente.";
                alert_and_redirect($statusMsg, '../subir/indexupload.php');
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "La subida ha fallado, por favor, repita otra vez.";
            } 
        }else{
            $statusMsg = "Lo sentimos, ha habido un error en la subida.";
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Lo sentimos, solo se pueden subir archivos JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, PDF, PPT y PPTX.';
    }
}else{
    $statusMsg = 'Por favor, selecciona un archivo para subir.';
}
```

alert_and_redirect($statusMsg, '../subir/indexupload.php');

?>

Ya está solucionado. Dejo aquí el código de lo que buscaba.

```
$insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO images (file_name, file_path, tags) VALUES ('".$fileName."', '". $targetFilePath ."', ('". $chk . $tags ."'))");
```

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres con `tags` y `tags 2` ¿Qué es la variable `$tags`, un array o algo así? Si es una variable simple sólo tienes que repetirla en la parte de `VALUES`. Aunque tu práctica me suena a **redundancia de datos**, una práctica que deberías evitar en bases de datos.

Comment: Lo que estoy buscando es juntar dos partes de un formulario en una columna. $tags es un array.
Quiero juntar los datos de los dos arrays $chk y $tags en la misma columna de la base de datos llamada tags así borro la columna llamada tags2

Comment: OK. Acabo de escribir una respuesta, pero si `$tags` es un array (supongo que con dos valores), entonces tienes que sacar cada valor por parte, por el índice `0` y el índice `1`, ahora modifico la respuesta.

Comment: Revisa la respuesta editada.

Comment: Tu comentario en mi respuesta me deja confundido. ¿Podrías por favor [edit] la pregunta y aclarar mejor lo que quieres, si es posible con un ejemplo? Si quieres juntar datos de columnas que ya existen para normalizar, lo que deberías hacer es un `UPDATE` usando `REPLACE` (si entendí bien tu comentario). Esto no tiene nada que ver con un `INSERT`.

Comment: En cualquier caso, si `$tags` es un array puedes usar `implode` para sacarlo como cadena y luego juntarlo con la otra variable mediante concatenación y usarla en el `INSERT`. Pero esto no te va a resolver el problema si quieres normalizar realmente deberías hacer un `UPDATE` con los valores que ya existen y normalizar también en el código haciendo que recoja solamente un valor para `tags`.

Answer (score 1):

### Si `$tags` es un array con dos valores

Tienes que sacar cada valor por su índice e incluirlo en el `VALUES`, algo así:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO images (file_name, file_path, tags, tags2) VALUES ('$fileName', '$targetFilePath', '$chk', ' $tags[0]', '$tags[1]')";
$insert = $db->query($sql);
```

Aquí, mediante `$tags[0]`obtendrías el primer valor del array y con `$tags[1]` el segundo valor.

Las notas 1 y 2 siguen siendo válidas para este caso.

### <s>Respuesta anterior: si es para insertar un mismo valor en dos columnas</s>

Para insertar el mismo valor de `$tags` en ambas columnas, sólo tienes que repetir la variable en la lista de `VALUES`, algo así:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO images (file_name, file_path, tags, tags2) VALUES ('$fileName', '$targetFilePath', '$chk', ' $tags', '$tags')";
$insert = $db->query($sql);
```

### NOTAS:

1. Puedes escribir código más claro evitando tantas concatenaciones. Si rodeas la variable por comillas dobles, luego puedes usar comillas simples dentro sin problemas
2. Tu consulta es vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Considera usar **consultas preparadas**.
3. <s>Dos columnas con los mismos datos suena a **redundancia de datos**. Deberías evitarlo en bases de datos</s>

Comment: Gracias por contestar. Pero lo que esto buscando es juntar los datos que me da $chk y los datos que me da $tags y juntarlos en la columna de la base de datos llamada "tags" para asi borrar la llamada "tags2"

Comment: Gracias por todo.